# LoadError: cannot load such file to try run the rake doc:guides command in rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

Can you help me with the installation of the ruby on rails guides in my local machine? . I am using

ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [i686-linux]
Rails 4.0.0
rvm
Linux 12.04

I need the documentation de rails 4.0, but I have a problem when I write the command

```
 rake doc/guides.
```

Rais tells me there is an error LoadError: cannot load such file

Previously I installed the RedCloth gem but it's not working

GemFile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
  gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'RedCloth'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  ..........................................................
  ................................................................
Ubuntu console

```
trabajo@fernando:~/RubyOnRailsGuides/blog$ bundle
Using rake 10.3.2
Using RedCloth 4.2.9
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activesupport 4.0.0
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.0
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.0
Using activemodel 4.0.0
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.2.1
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.0.0
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using jbuilder 1.5.3
Using jquery-rails 3.1.1
Using json 1.8.1
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
Using rails 4.0.0
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.2.2
Using uglifier 2.5.1
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Say me redcloth installed Using RedCloth 4.2.9

```
trabajo@fernando:~/RubyOnRailsGuides/blog$ rake doc:guides
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/trabajo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@guides/gems/guides/rails_guides
/home/trabajo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@guides/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@guides/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@guides/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@guides/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@guides/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:72:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => doc:guides
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Help me?